# Is it possible to automatically declare a method into header file(.h) in appCode?

Tags: objective-c, appcode

I have using appCode.

I want to automatically be declared a method into heder file by appCode's some feature, when I write a method in @implementation file.

ex) I write a method in @implementation file.

```
@implementation myClass
- (void)testMethod{
}
@end
```

automatically declare a method into @interface file.

```
@interface myClass
- (void)testMethod;  <== automatically insert.
@end
```

How to automatically declare method into header file by appcode's feature?

Comment: AppCode? - Then why question tagged with 'xcode'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With caret cursor at testMethod name invoke Opt+Enter and choose "Declare method in interface" from the list.